# Pandas python, how to make columns from a list into a DataFrame, and clean it from unnecessary info

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list:

```
sorted_info = ['  1:  surgery?\n', '  2:  Age\n', '  3:  Hospital Number\n', '  4:  rectal temperature\n', '  5:  pulse\n', '          - is a reflection of the heart condition: 30 -40 is normal for adults\n', '  6:  respiratory rate\n', '  7:  temperature of extremities\n', '          - possible values:\n', '  8:  peripheral pulse\n', '          - possible values are:\n', '  9:  mucous membranes\n', '          - possible values are:\n', ' 10: capillary refill time\n', " 11: pain - a subjective judgement of the horse's pain level\n", '          - possible values:\n', ' 12: peristalsis\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 13: abdominal distension\n', ' 14: nasogastric tube\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 15: nasogastric reflux\n', ' 16: nasogastric reflux PH\n', ' 17: rectal examination - feces\n', ' 18: abdomen\n', ' 19: packed cell volume\n', ' 20: total protein\n', ' 21: abdominocentesis appearance\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 22: abdomcentesis total protein\n', ' 23: outcome\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 24: surgical lesion?\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 25, 26, 27: type of lesion\n', ' 28: cp_data\n']
```

further, I do:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.DataFrame(sorted_info) 

0   1: surgery?\n 1 2:
   Age\n 2  3: Hospital Number\n 3  4: rectal temperature\n 4   5: pulse\n
   5    - is a reflection of the heart condi... 6   6: respiratory rate\n
   7    7: temperature of extremities\n 8   - possible values:\n 9  8:
   peripheral pulse\n 10    - possible values are:\n 11 9: mucous
   membranes\n 12   - possible values are:\n 13 10: capillary refill
   time\n 14    11: pain - a subjective judgement of the hors... 15 -
   possible values:\n 16    12: peristalsis\n 17    - possible values:\n
   18   13: abdominal distension\n 19   14: nasogastric tube\n 20   - possible
   values:\n 21 15: nasogastric reflux\n 22 16: nasogastric reflux PH\n
   23   17: rectal examination - feces\n 24 18: abdomen\n 25    19: packed
   cell volume\n 26 20: total protein\n 27  21: abdominocentesis
   appearance\n 28  - possible values:\n 29 22: abdomcentesis total
   protein\n 30 23: outcome\n 31    - possible values:\n 32 24: surgical
   lesion?\n 33 - possible values:\n 34 25, 26, 27: type of lesion\n
   35   28: cp_data\n
```

So I am trying to sort in that DF will look like:

```
 Col1  Col2
  1:   surgery
  2:   Age
  3:   Hospital Number
```

etc.
Any suggestions how to split Series into 2 Cols and clean/delete rest of info?

Comment: How is "unnecessary info" defined? This question, as posed, is extremely specific to a single case and unlikely to help others on StackOverflow. Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Explain this language feature to me" is off-topic for StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation. We expect you to work through the available tutorials and do some honest attempts first.

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

sorted_info = ['  1:  surgery?\n', '  2:  Age\n', '  3:  Hospital Number\n', '  4:  rectal temperature\n', '  5:  pulse\n', '          - is a reflection of the heart condition: 30 -40 is normal for adults\n', '  6:  respiratory rate\n', '  7:  temperature of extremities\n', '          - possible values:\n', '  8:  peripheral pulse\n', '          - possible values are:\n', '  9:  mucous membranes\n', '          - possible values are:\n', ' 10: capillary refill time\n', " 11: pain - a subjective judgement of the horse's pain level\n", '          - possible values:\n', ' 12: peristalsis\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 13: abdominal distension\n', ' 14: nasogastric tube\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 15: nasogastric reflux\n', ' 16: nasogastric reflux PH\n', ' 17: rectal examination - feces\n', ' 18: abdomen\n', ' 19: packed cell volume\n', ' 20: total protein\n', ' 21: abdominocentesis appearance\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 22: abdomcentesis total protein\n', ' 23: outcome\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 24: surgical lesion?\n', '          - possible values:\n', ' 25, 26, 27: type of lesion\n', ' 28: cp_data\n']

sorted_info = [x.strip() for x in sorted_info]

joined_list = []

for x in sorted_info:
    if x.startswith('-'):
        joined_list[-1] += ' ' + x
    else:
        joined_list.append(x)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(joined_list)

df[['Number', 'Text']] = df[0].str.split(':', n=1, expand=True)

del df[0]

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
        Number                                               Text
0            1                                           surgery?
1            2                                                Age
2            3                                    Hospital Number
3            4                                 rectal temperature
4            5    pulse - is a reflection of the heart conditi...
5            6                                   respiratory rate
6            7      temperature of extremities - possible values:
7            8            peripheral pulse - possible values are:
8            9            mucous membranes - possible values are:
9           10                              capillary refill time
10          11   pain - a subjective judgement of the horse's ...
11          12                     peristalsis - possible values:
12          13                               abdominal distension
13          14                nasogastric tube - possible values:
14          15                                 nasogastric reflux
15          16                              nasogastric reflux PH
16          17                         rectal examination - feces
17          18                                            abdomen
18          19                                 packed cell volume
19          20                                      total protein
20          21     abdominocentesis appearance - possible values:
21          22                        abdomcentesis total protein
22          23                         outcome - possible values:
23          24                surgical lesion? - possible values:
24  25, 26, 27                                     type of lesion
25          28                                            cp_data
```

---

**Additional:**

If you wanted to then go forwards and expand the `25, 26, 27` values in row 24 try:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
   Number                                               Text
0       1                                           surgery?
1       2                                                Age
2       3                                    Hospital Number
3       4                                 rectal temperature
4       5    pulse - is a reflection of the heart conditi...
5       6                                   respiratory rate
6       7      temperature of extremities - possible values:
7       8            peripheral pulse - possible values are:
8       9            mucous membranes - possible values are:
9      10                              capillary refill time
10     11   pain - a subjective judgement of the horse's ...
11     12                     peristalsis - possible values:
12     13                               abdominal distension
13     14                nasogastric tube - possible values:
14     15                                 nasogastric reflux
15     16                              nasogastric reflux PH
16     17                         rectal examination - feces
17     18                                            abdomen
18     19                                 packed cell volume
19     20                                      total protein
20     21     abdominocentesis appearance - possible values:
21     22                        abdomcentesis total protein
22     23                         outcome - possible values:
23     24                surgical lesion? - possible values:
24     25                                     type of lesion
25     26                                     type of lesion
26     27                                     type of lesion
27     28                                            cp_data
```

Answer (score 1):

**We can do it this way:**

1. Read the list `sorted_info` into a Pandas Series.
2. Use [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with Regex to extract the number tag and main contents of one line of text.  Ready with `Col1` and `Col2` after the extraction.
3. For continuation line without number tag, we use [`.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) to forward fill the missing tag number
4. Group by the tag number in `Col1` and join texts with continuation line based on the same tag number

**Here, the codes:**

```
# Read the list `sorted_info` into a Pandas Series:
s = pd.Series(sorted_info)

# Extract the number tag and main contents of a line of text:
df = s.str.extract(r'\s*(?:(?P<Col1>\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*:)|-)\s*(?P<Col2>.*)', expand=True)

# For continuation lines without number tag, forward fill the missing tag number
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].ffill()

# Group by the tag numbers in `Col1` and join text in continuation line based on the same tag number
df_out = df.groupby('Col1', sort=False, as_index=False).agg(' - '.join)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


           Col1                                                                         Col2
0            1:                                                                     surgery?
1            2:                                                                          Age
2            3:                                                              Hospital Number
3            4:                                                           rectal temperature
4            5:  pulse - is a reflection of the heart condition: 30 -40 is normal for adults
5            6:                                                             respiratory rate
6            7:                                temperature of extremities - possible values:
7            8:                                      peripheral pulse - possible values are:
8            9:                                      mucous membranes - possible values are:
9           10:                                                        capillary refill time
10          11:   pain - a subjective judgement of the horse's pain level - possible values:
11          12:                                               peristalsis - possible values:
12          13:                                                         abdominal distension
13          14:                                          nasogastric tube - possible values:
14          15:                                                           nasogastric reflux
15          16:                                                        nasogastric reflux PH
16          17:                                                   rectal examination - feces
17          18:                                                                      abdomen
18          19:                                                           packed cell volume
19          20:                                                                total protein
20          21:                               abdominocentesis appearance - possible values:
21          22:                                                  abdomcentesis total protein
22          23:                                                   outcome - possible values:
23          24:                                          surgical lesion? - possible values:
24  25, 26, 27:                                                               type of lesion
25          28:                                                                      cp_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first clean the data itself. It is unfortunate that it reaches the part where you want to make a DataFrame in such a noisy form. Ideally, the cleanup should come closer to the data collection itself.

Generally speaking, data cleaning is highly domain-dependent. For simple string cleanup, usually a combination of `string.split()`, `re.match()` and list comprehensions can go a long way.

For your specific case, the following gives good results (exercise for the reader: understand each bit of the expression, by trying reduced forms of it, starting by e.g. `[v.splitlines()[0].split(':', 1) for v in sorted_info]` building up toward the final form):

```py
import re

cleaned = [
    [s.split(' - ', 1)[0].strip().rstrip('?')
     for s in v.splitlines()[0].split(':', 1)]
    for v in sorted_info if re.match('^ *\d+:', v)
]

>>> cleaned
[['1', 'surgery'],
 ['2', 'Age'],
 ['3', 'Hospital Number'],
 ['4', 'rectal temperature'],
 ['5', 'pulse'],
 ['6', 'respiratory rate'],
 ['7', 'temperature of extremities'],
 ['8', 'peripheral pulse'],
 ['9', 'mucous membranes'],
 ['10', 'capillary refill time'],
 ['11', 'pain'],
 ['12', 'peristalsis'],
 ['13', 'abdominal distension'],
 ['14', 'nasogastric tube'],
 ['15', 'nasogastric reflux'],
 ['16', 'nasogastric reflux PH'],
 ['17', 'rectal examination'],
 ['18', 'abdomen'],
 ['19', 'packed cell volume'],
 ['20', 'total protein'],
 ['21', 'abdominocentesis appearance'],
 ['22', 'abdomcentesis total protein'],
 ['23', 'outcome'],
 ['24', 'surgical lesion'],
 ['28', 'cp_data']]

# and
df = pd.DataFrame(cleaned, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])

>>> df
   Col1                         Col2
0     1                      surgery
1     2                          Age
2     3              Hospital Number
3     4           rectal temperature
4     5                        pulse
5     6             respiratory rate
6     7   temperature of extremities
7     8             peripheral pulse
8     9             mucous membranes
9    10        capillary refill time
10   11                         pain
11   12                  peristalsis
12   13         abdominal distension
13   14             nasogastric tube
14   15           nasogastric reflux
15   16        nasogastric reflux PH
16   17           rectal examination
17   18                      abdomen
18   19           packed cell volume
19   20                total protein
20   21  abdominocentesis appearance
21   22  abdomcentesis total protein
22   23                      outcome
23   24              surgical lesion
24   28                      cp_data
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It's fine to downvote an answer if there is a problem with it, or if it is not useful to solve the problem in the question, but in either case the author would be grateful to hear what the problem is.